About the details of Fundamental solution of wave operator
The following is part of the PDE lecture notes (the first two parts are some definitions and propositions, the key part I want to ask is below the last dividing line). What I want to ask is how the conclusion that "the support set of $\square E_{+}$ is only at the origin" is obtained. I can't get this from the properties of the $\chi_+$ function.

We assume that wave operator$$
\square = -\partial_{tt}^2 + \Delta.
$$
By definition, this is a constant coefficient differential operator on $\mathbb{R}^{1+n}$. We aim to study the fundamental solution of this operator. First, we define the distribution on $\mathbb{R}$:
$$
\chi_+^a = \frac{x_+^a}{\Gamma(a+1)}, \quad a > -1, \quad x_+ = \max\{0, x\}.
$$
By definition, we have:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\chi_+^a = \chi_+^{a-1}, \quad a > 0.
$$
Using this relationship, $\chi_+^a$ can be extended to all $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Our focus is on cases where $a$ is an integer or a half-integer.


Proposition 1.23 (Fundamental solution of the wave operator).
The forward fundamental solution of the wave operator is given by the distribution:
$$
E_{+}(t, x) = -\frac{\pi^{\frac{1-n}{2}}}{2} H(t) \chi_{+}^{-\frac{n-1}{2}}\left(t^2 - |x|^2\right),
$$
where $H(t)$ is the Heaviside function, and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is the spatial variable.
Proof:
Clearly, $H(t)$ is locally integrable on $\mathbb{R}^{1+n}$ and is supported on $\{(t, x) \mid t \geq 0\}$. We need to interpret $\chi_{+}^{-\frac{n-1}{2}}\left(t^2 - |x|^2\right)$. When $t^2 + |x|^2 > 0$, the function $t^2 - |x|^2$ is non-degenerate. Thus, based on the earlier discussion, $\chi_{+}^{-\frac{n-1}{2}}\left(t^2 - |x|^2\right)$ can be viewed as the pullback of $\chi_{+}^{-\frac{n-1}{2}}$ under the mapping $t^2 - |x|^2$, satisfying the chain rule for derivatives. At the origin, it can be defined as:
$$
\left\langle\chi_{+}^{-\frac{n-1}{2}}\left(t^2 - |x|^2\right), \varphi(t, x)\right\rangle = \left\langle\chi_{+}^{-\frac{n-1}{2}}, \frac{1}{2} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{\varphi\left(\sqrt{s + |x|^2}, x\right)}{\sqrt{s + |x|^2}} dx \right\rangle.
$$
Of course, the issue here is that the integral is not a smooth function of $s$. Note that the support of $\chi_{+}^{-\frac{n-1}{2}}$ is on $s \geq 0$, so only $s \geq 0$ needs to be considered. The integral is smooth with respect to $s$ for $s > 0$, and at $s = 0$, it is $(n-2)/2$-times continuously differentiable. By combining this with the definition of $\chi_{+}^{-\frac{n-1}{2}}$, the distribution can be extended to the function space $C^k$, allowing a rigorous definition of the distribution, though further details are omitted here.



Inside the light cone ($t^2 + |x|^2 > 0$), by applying the chain rule for the pullback of distributions, we compute:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\square\left(\chi_{+}^{-\frac{n-1}{2}}\left(t^2 - |x|^2\right)\right) 
&= -\partial_t\left(2t \chi_{+}^{-\frac{n+1}{2}}\left(t^2 - |x|^2\right)\right) - \partial_{i}\left(2x_i \chi_{+}^{-\frac{n+1}{2}}\left(t^2 - |x|^2\right)\right) \\
&= -2(n+1) \chi_{+}^{-\frac{n+1}{2}}\left(t^2 - |x|^2\right) - 4\left(t^2 - |x|^2\right) \chi_{+}^{-\frac{n+3}{2}}\left(t^2 - |x|^2\right).
\end{aligned}
$$
Observe that for any $a \in \mathbb{R}$, we have:
$$
x \chi_{+}^a = x \frac{x_{+}^a}{\Gamma(a+1)} = \frac{x_{+}^{a+1}}{\Gamma(a+2)} \cdot \frac{\Gamma(a+2)}{\Gamma(a+1)} = (a+1) \chi_{+}^{a+1}.
$$
This demonstrates that the support of the distribution $\square E_{+}$ is concentrated at the origin $(t = 0, x = 0)$.

$\color{red}{\text{There is no guarantee that there are no typos in this notes.}}$$\color{red}{\text{If there are any, please point them out.}}$
